# Proving recurrence relation with induction: $T(n) = T(n-1) + n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, asymptotics

I have to prove that the bound of the following relation is $\theta(n^2)$ by induction-

$$T(n) = T(n-1) +  n$$

1. should i seprate my induction into two sections - 
   to claim  that $T(n) = O(n^2)$ and $T(n) = \Omega(n^2)$ and prove each case, or should i expand the relation and then formulate my claims ?
2. should my two equations be the same , but with diffrent sign  -->   $\leq$ and $\geq$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another path to spread a different light. From the identity,
$$
T_{n} = T_{n-1} + n, \qquad n=1,2,3,\ldots, 
$$ one may obtain
$$
T_{n} - T_{n-1} = n, 
$$ then summing from $n=1$ to $n=N$ terms telescope,
$$
T_N- T_0=\sum_{n=1}^{N}n, 
$$ that is 
$$
T_N- T_0=\frac{N(N+1)}2 
$$ giving, as $N \to \infty$,

> $$
> \frac{N^2}2\leq T_N \leq N^2
> $$

as wanted.

Comment: Thanks! , another question - should i explain or show by expanding why i chose my claims that way?

Comment: @BarakMi You are welcome! Not necessary, I think.